# Serverless: deploy particular profile

Tags: serverless-framework

In the `serverless.yml`, the deployment profiles are set like this

```
custom:
defaultStage: dev
profiles:
  dev: b***2_dev
  prod: b***2_prod
  suku: b***2_suku
```

While the default deploy is `dev`, I would like to deploy the profile `suku` without changing the defaultStage.

What is the command for this? `sls deploy --profile suku` didn't work

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On newest versions of serverless (currently 1.26.1), you can provide the argument `--aws-profile`

ex: `sls --aws-profile suku deploy`
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials#using-the-aws-profile-option

However, in your case, another option could be to use "per stage" profile:

```
service: new-service
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage}
  profile: ${self:custom.profiles.${self:provider.stage}}
custom:
  defaultStage: dev
  profiles:
    dev: devProfile
    prod: prodProfile
```

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials#per-stage-profiles

Answer (score 9):

The --profile argument is not currently supported. You can set the environment by setting the AWS_PROFILE environment variable as appropriate. To run a command using a particular profile other than the default one in the system settings, you can do:

On Linux & OSX:

```
AWS_PROFILE=suku sls deploy
```

On Windows:

```
cmd /C "set AWS_PROFILE=suku && sls deploy"
```

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that your aws profile is setup in `~/.aws/credentials` you can the run `export AWS_PROFILE=selectedAccount`. For the rest of your shell session *selectedAccount* will be your default profile. You can now run `sls deploy` and it will deploy to *selectedAccount*

Answer (score 0):

You must use `--aws-profile` not `--profile`.

```bash
serverless deploy --aws-profile suku
```